# Showing that two vector spaces aren't isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-space-isomorphism

Here is a part of an exercise (from a book) I can't figure out how to solve :

Les $V$ be the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. We define also the functions $e_i(n)$ by $e_i(n)=1$ if $i=n$ and $0$ otherwise. We set $B=\lbrace e_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ and $W=span(B)$.

The aim is to show that there is no isomorphism between $V$ and $W$.

I really don't see anything, really... Can you help me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Cardinality.  Cardinality. (the second one is mostly for the character limit, but it's also worth repeating)

Comment: It's not hard to find a function that's not a *finite* linear combination of the $e_i$'s. That's the trick here ... linear combinations are implicitly finite.

Comment: @user4894: It just shows that the inclusion $W \subset V$ is strict, that is $W \neq V$, but it does not prove that $V$ and $W$ are not isomorphic. Indeed, let $A$ be any infinite-dimensional vector space and fix a basis $\{e_i \mid i \in I \}$. Then, defining $B_j= \langle e_i, \ i \in I \backslash \{ j \} \rangle$, you have $B_j \subsetneq A$ whereas $A$ and $B_j$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @Seirios You're right, I fooled myself, see below.

Answer (score 2):

For any $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, define $f_I : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_I(n)=1$ if $n \in I$ and $0$ otherwise. You can show that $\{ f_I \mid \emptyset \neq I \subset \mathbb{N}\}$ is a family of linearly independent functions of cardinality $|\mathfrak{P}(\mathbb{N})|= |\mathbb{R}|$. Therefore, the dimension of $V$ is uncountable whereas $\dim(W)$ is clearly countable.

Comment: $B$ is a basis for $W$. So $dim(W)$ is the size of $\mathbb{N}$. But $B$ does not span $V$... I don't know about $V$, what else can I say?

Comment: Isn't the dimension of $V$ infinite? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: $W \subset V$ so $V$ is clearly infinite-dimensional. However, $\dim(W)$ is countable whereas $\dim(V)$ is not: look at its cardinality.

Comment: This is quite unhelpful. Actually both spaces have the same cardinality (namely that of $\Bbb R$), though they don't have the same dimension.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You are completely right, when I wrote my answer I thought that $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}|= |\mathfrak{P}(\mathbb{P})|$, which is clearly false. I edited my answer. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: See my comment above. Find a function that's not a *finite* linear combination of the elements of B. What does any element of B look like?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Show that the [algebraic] dual of $W$ is isomorphic to $V$, and use the fact that $W$ is infinitely dimensional.

(Other hints might include showing that every subspace of $W$ is countable or finitely generated; whereas $V$ has subspaces of infinite dimension which are Banach spaces. Then use the fact that a Banach space cannot have a countable dimension, for example by using the Baire Category Theorem.)

Comment: A nice observation, I did not notice it. Well done! +1

Answer (score 0):

**RETRACTED, this argument doesn't seem to work. My bad.**

No cardinality argument is needed. All you need to do is find a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that's not in the linear span of $\{e_i\}$.

What does an element of $W$ look like? It's some function $g = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i$ for some real numbers $\{c_i\}$. The point being that this is a *finite* sum by definition of linear span.

So every element of $W$ is a sequence having only *finitely many nonzero terms*.

Now the answer becomes obvious. The function $f(n) = 1$ is a sequence containing infinitely many nonzero terms; so it can not possibly be a linear combination of any of the $\{e_i\}$'s, so these two vector spaces are not the same.

Comment: This shows that the inclusion is not an isomorphism, but have you ruled out the possibility of any isomorphism?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I'm in the process of writing that up now.

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan on doing that since two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if their dimensions have the same cardinality. (Assuming AC.)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip You're right this is a little tricker than I thought at first ... (frantically waving hands)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip   ps ... yes my argument fails totally, for all I know some isomorphism maps $e_1$ to (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...) and my argument falls apart.